# Unable to assign value to variable with convert

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(10)='',@I INT=0,@RAND_ CHAR(1)

WHILE @I<10
BEGIN
    SET @RAND_=CONVERT(CHAR,FLOOR(RAND()*10))
    SET @ID+=@RAND_
    SET @I+=1
END
SELECT @ID
```

If i make it like that it returns me a 10 digit number,
but if i try it like that

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20)='',@I INT=0

WHILE @I<10
BEGIN
    SET @ID+=CONVERT(CHAR,FLOOR(RAND()*10))
    SET @I+=1
END
SELECT @ID
```

it returns only 1 digit.Why,isn't it the same thing?

Comment: To be honest, it's curious for me too. Anyway, if you change in your second query `CHAR` by `VARCHAR(1)` you will get again a 10 digits value

Comment: Never use `char` or `varchar` without a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
SET @ID += CONVERT(CHAR, FLOOR(RAND()*10))
```

**The length is not being specified. The default length is 30, and `char` will pad the rest of the length with spaces.** So `@ID` is already filled, and therefore cannot be added to.

[This is fully documented online:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> When `n` isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If `n` isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Had you specified the length, or used `varchar`, this would not have happened.

```
SET @ID += CONVERT(CHAR(1), FLOOR(RAND()*10))
```

**Always specify `char` and `varchar` lengths explicitly**

Answer (score 0):

The varchar has to be the same type for convert to work correctly.

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20)='',@I INT=0
DECLARE @ID_Convert VARCHAR(20)=''

WHILE @I<10
BEGIN
    SET @ID_Convert = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FLOOR(RAND()*10))
    SET @ID += @ID_Convert
    SET @I+=1
END
SELECT @ID
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be the same type per se, it just needs a length, or it needs to be `varchar` to stop automatic padding. Right answer, wrong reason